# Testing Facebook Authentication on Local Host (Laravel 4)

Tags: facebook, laravel, localhost, laravel-4, hybridauth

I am trying to set up Facebook authentication with hybridauth in Laravel 4.  I would like to test the authentication on my localhost server.

The domain where I would like the authentication to occur on is at:

```
http://localhost:8888/crowdsets/laravel-master/public/fans/landing
```

I have included the base url in the config file as:

```
http://localhost:8888/crowdsets/laravel-master/public/fans/landing/auth/
```

In Facebook, for my app, I am trying to set up the local host as the Site Url and App Domain.

I used:

Site Url:  `http://localhost:8888`

App Domain:  `localhost:8888`

I am receiving the error from FB:

Error
App Domains: localhost:8888 is not a valid domain.

Do you have any idea what I should be using in order to test this authentication system on my localhost?  I am using MAMP on a Mac OS X 10.7.5 machine.

Comment: create vistual host and change localhost to something else, not sure, maybe error lies in 8888, but still you can solve it with virtualhost

Comment: how do i create a virtual host?

Comment: type in google create virtual host apache

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working for my Rails app locally without using a virtual host. Here are the steps I used:

- Go to `http://developers.facebook.com/`, create, and setup your app
- When inside the dashboard, click "Settings"
- Click "Add Platform"
- Choose website (for authentication via the web app)
- Add `http://localhost:3000/` as "Site URL" (and "Mobile URL" if necessary)
- Add `localhost` to "App Domains" above
- Click Save

Whereas you have your App Domain as `localhost:88888`, I believe it should just be `localhost`.